# How to call evaluateJavaScript() function from Qt?

Tags: javascript, qt, qwebview

I am not able to call a javascript function from QT .

I am using the below code

QT code :
    `QWebFrame *frame = m_d->m_webView->page()->mainFrame();`
    `frame->evaluateJavaScript("displayhello()");`

```
 Here `displayhello()` is the `Javascript` function defined in the HTML file.
```

HTML code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   function displaymessage(str)
   {
       alert(str);
   }
   function displayhello()
   {
       alert("Hello");
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onClick="displayhello()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone give me any pointers  why the Javascript function is not getting called.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old but in case someone has the same:

Always check Dev Tools to see what the JavaScript console tells you.
You can enable devtools by adding this line tou your QT main function

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);
```

Now by right clicking->inspect, console, you would have seen the JS interpret error.

Answer (score 0):

You should have lower case 'c' in 'onclick':

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displayhello()">
```

Comment: QWebFrame *frame = m_d->m_webView->page()->mainFrame(); frame->evaluateJavaScript("displayhello()");

evaluateJavaScript is not calling displayhello() from HTML file.

Comment: HTML attribute names are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

`QVariant holdInformation = map->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript (QString ("displayhello ()"));`

Replace `map` by your desired class name.

Also, try using `onload`.
`<body onload = "displayhello()" topmargin = "0" leftmargin = "0">`