# QT String not working for JavaScript call

Tags: qstring, qwebview

Hello I have a `QWebView` and the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataListLongitude.size(); i++) {
    QString appending = "addMarker(" + QString(dataListLatitude.at(i)) + ", " + QString(dataListLongitude.at(i)) + ", '" + QString(dataListFileName.at(i)) + "');";
    scriptStr << appending;
    frame->evaluateJavaScript( appending );
}
frame->evaluateJavaScript( "addMarker(27.2131, 16.3242, 'Test');" );
```

However only the last (manual) attempt is working (I have an alert `message` in my HTML file).

Comment: I now also checked with args(), with and without ' and with and without QString() for the strings... None worked...

Comment: Did you check the contents of `appending`? It's possible your string is not being formatted the way you expect.

Comment: Hi, I have had different outputs like: addMarker('47.565498', '7.626270', 'IMG_7636.JPG');
and addMarker(47.565498, 7.626270, 'IMG_7636.JPG');
But none of these worked either...

Comment: I don't know much about Qt but you can find better debug information [by accessing the Dev Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18060124/371184).